# override material design classes in css

Tags: css

I am using react-toolbox and react-toolbox-themr dependency to integrate material design in reactjs. While using card component, I want to customize the css for title and subtitle which are attributes of tag. How can I add css to subtitle and title of card?

My component looks like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Display} from './Display.js';
import './toolbox/theme.css';
import theme from './toolbox/theme'
import ThemeProvider from 'react-toolbox/lib/ThemeProvider'
import Button from 'react-toolbox/lib/button/Button.js';
import IconButton from 'react-toolbox/lib/button/IconButton.js';
import Avatar from 'react-toolbox/lib/avatar/Avatar.js';
import Card from 'react-toolbox/lib/card/Card.js';
import CardTitle from 'react-toolbox/lib/card/CardTitle.js';
import CardText from 'react-toolbox/lib/card/CardText.js';
import {Constants} from './constants.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';
const test = require('./App.css')

export class QueryList extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dummyText = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
    this.state = {
        querylist: []
    };
}

 componentDidMount(){
    this.loadData();
}

  loadData(){
      var me=this;
        axios({
          method:Constants.methods[0],
          url:Constants.URLConst+"/Query?pageNum=1&totalperPage=15&userid=0",
          headers: Constants.headers

        }).then(function(response){
              me.setState({
                  querylist: response.data.QueryListDetails.QueryData
              })
        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log(error);
        })
  }

render(){

    var i=1;
    var listQueries = this.state.querylist.map(function(item) {
        item.QueryPostedDate = "Posted On "+moment(item.QueryPostedDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:Ss A');
      return (
            <Card className="query-card" key={i++}>
                <CardTitle
                  className={test.themedCardTitle}
                  title={item.QueryText}
                  subtitle={item.QueryPostedDate}
                  theme={test}
                />
            </Card>
      );
    });

    return(
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div>
            <Display/>
            {listQueries}
        </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
        )
}
```

}

In App.css I have something like this.

```
.themedCardTitle.cardTitle {
  .subtitle {
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

But subtitle is not turning pink in color. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.themedCardTitle.cardTitle` what syntax is that? What are you trying to achieve with it, applying it to both these classes?

Comment: I referred it from here https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/688

Comment: Share the elements you are trying to style and the current css rules that apply.

Comment: Yeah that syntax is SCSS, not plain CSS. It won't work in a regular CSS file. If you want to apply to multiple classes or to a sub element or something in regular CSS, you'll have to find out the way to do it. Your `App.css` isn't valid. That's why it doesn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

In App.css, add a class which will have higher priority. For example:

```
p.card-subtitle{ color:pink; }
```

Note that I am using 'p' because that's the html tag of the CartTitle component.

Then import the styes just like you import 'themes.css' (provided you have a style loader):

```
import './App.css'
```

Finally, reference the class in your component:

```
<CardTitle className='card-subtitle'/>
```

Alternatively you can try to use !important to ensure higher priority of the style instead of using the html tag:

```
.card-subtitle{ color:pink !important;}
```

Comment: Here you have some cases where to use it. https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/
Anyway, you can use the first style. I think it should work as CardTitle should always be a 'p'